# ES6: how to set the instance to null inside class?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to use

```
if (instanceOfClass === null){
    // ...
}
```

The `instanceOfClass` variable dynamically becomes to null during script and then the new instance will be assigned if necessary. Also, I don't want to write `instanceOfClass = null`: if class will destroy it's instance itself inside the respective method, it will be more elegant:

```
SomeClass{

    // ...

    cancelOperation(){
        this = null; // don't work
    }
}

instanceOfClass = new SomeClass();
instanceOfClass.cancelOperation();
instanceOfClass = new SomeClass();
```

What I need to write instead of `this = null;` to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroying a class from within is bad practice, instead if you want to assign a new instance use a flag to mark the class is ready to be deleted.

```
MyClass {
  readyToBeDeleted: boolean = false;

  cancelOperation() {
    this.readyToBeDeleted = true;
  }
}
```

then from the outside check and re-assign if needed:

```
if (myClass.readyToBeDeleted) {
  myClass = new MyClass();
}
```